# Why does this python dictionary get created out of order using setdefault()?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, setdefault

I'm just starting to play around with Python (VBA background).  Why does this dictionary get created out of order?   Shouldn't it be a:1, b:2...etc.?

```
class Card:
def county(self):
    c = 0
    l = 0
    groupL = {}  # groupL for Loop
    for n in range(0,13):
        c += 1
        l = chr(n+97)
        groupL.setdefault(l,c)
    return groupL

pick_card = Card()
group = pick_card.county()
print group
```

here's the output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4, 'g': 7, 'f': 6, 'i': 9, 'h': 8, 'k': 11, 'j': 10, 'm': 13, 'l': 12}
```

or, does it just get printed out of order?

Comment: As a side note, why are you using setdefault here? There are plenty of cases where that's a useful function, but for just inserting stuff into a dictionary, `groupL[l] = c` is probably what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary, how to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dictionaries have no order in python.  In other words, when you iterate over a dictionary, the order that the keys/items are "yielded" is not the order that you put them into the dictionary.  (Try your code on a different version of python and you're likely to get differently ordered output). If you want a dictionary that is ordered, you need a `collections.OrderedDict` which wasn't introduced until python 2.7.  You can find equivalent recipes on `ActiveState` if you're using an older version of python.  However, often it's good enough to just sort the items (e.g. `sorted(mydict.items())`.

**EDIT** as requested, an OrderedDict example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
groupL = OrderedDict()  # groupL for Loop
c = 0
for n in range(0,13):
    c += 1
    l = chr(n+97)
    groupL.setdefault(l,c)

print (groupL)
```

Comment: First, thanks!  But, why would the numbers and letters go in specifically out of order?  They are being entered in order via the loop, no?  Regardless, could you give an quick example of collections.OrderedDict?  Many thanks.

Comment: @dwstein Virtually all Python implementations use [hash maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_map) to allow extremely fast access to the dictionary's values by key.

Comment: @dwstein: It *doesn't matter* what order they are entered in.

Comment: I think i'm getting it.  the fact that it doesn't matter is interesting.  going to have to wrap my brain around that.

Comment: @dwstein, if you're really insterested in what is hidden inside Python's dict, I strongly recommend you to read this article: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko -- That's quite a gem.  Thanks!  (I assume that is Cpython specific, but still quite neat).

Comment: @dwstein: it might help to think of a literal dictionary (as in "Merriam-Webster"). New words and definitions can be added to a dictionary with every new edition. But the order they're stored in has nothing to do with the order that they're added. They are stored in the order that makes it easiest to look them up. Python dictionaries work the same way.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- I never thought of it that way.  Interesting.  I've always been trying to avoid thinking about a literal dictionary because the order those are stored in are so obvious and `dict` objects have no obvious order (*to me*).  I never thought about how the order is the "obvious" one *for the computer*.

Comment: Unlike a physical dictionary, though, adding an element to a Python dict can cause all the other elements to be reordered.