# Why is this printing a key in two different ways?

Tags: python

Why is it that the `print key` yields a list of the names of the fruits but `print prices[key]` yields the numbers after each fruit? Should `key` print the same thing (the fruit names)?

Here's the code

```
    prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}
stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}

for key in prices:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % prices[key]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[key]
```

Here is the result

`orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0`

Comment: Key and prices[key] are not the same thing, why are you treating them as such? Google Python dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this python dictionary get created out of order using setdefault()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784860/why-does-this-python-dictionary-get-created-out-of-order-using-setdefault)

Answer (score 1):

The statement `for key in prices` gives you the keys of the dictionary.  The statement `print prices[key]` gives you the value associated with key.

Comment: So if I had just written:`print "price: %s" % prices[key] print "stock: %s" % stock[key]`Then I would have gotten a list of the fruits in each dictionary?

Comment: No, you would have gotten a list of prices and the and the number of each fruit in stock. When you do a `for thing in dictionary` thing will always be a key. What is it the actual outcome that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

NVM what I previously wrote (misread question). Like the other post states you are printing the key of the dictionary with the statement `print key` and then you are printing the value that is associated w/ the key when you do `print price[key]` so to print all in one like you can do the following

```
for key in prices:
    print "item: ", key, " price: ", prices[key], " stock: " stock[key]
```

The above will throw a key error if it does not exist in the stock dictionary FYI.

Here is a solid answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905166/3990806

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in prices:
```

is equivalent to:

```
for key in prices.keys():
```

That is, you are iterating over the *keys* of a dictionary. `prices[key]` is retrieving a *value* in the dictionary associated with the *corresponding key*. That is,

```
prices[key]
```

is equivalent to

```
prices.values()[prices.keys().index(key)]
```

If you want to get a *list of values* in a dictionary use `values()` method and if you want to get a list of keys (such as fruit names in your dictionaries) use the `keys()` method.