# Python accessing dictionary inside of dictionary returns distorted dict

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, tuples

I have recently been working on a python application that handles some sort of schedule. I have a dictionary that contains the number of days in a rotation in a schedule, and then each day contains a dictionary with each different part of the day. It looks like this:

```
schedule = {
'rotation': 6,
'1' : {'B': '8:32', 'C': '9:34', 'D' : '10:36', 'F':'12:11', 'G': '1:13', 'H':'2:15'},

'2' : {'A': '8:32', 'B': '9:34', 'C,' : '10:36', 'E':'12:11', 'F': '1:13', 'G,':'2:15'},

'3' : {'A': '8:32', 'B': '9:34', 'D,' : '10:36', 'E':'12:11', 'F': '1:13', 'H,':'2:15'},

'4' : {'A': '8:32', 'C': '9:34', 'D,' : '10:36', 'E':'12:11', 'G': '1:13', 'H,':'2:15'},


'5' : {'B' : '8:40', 'D' : '11:00', 'F' : '12:55', 'H' : '2:15' },

'6' : {'A' : '8:40', 'C' : '11:00', 'E' : '12:55', 'G' : '2:15' }

}
```

This all looks like it should work, yet when I print it out, I get a distorted dictionary that looks like it is sorted:

```
{'1': {'C': '9:34', 'B': '8:32', 'D': '10:36', 'G': '1:13', 'F': '12:11', 'H': '2:15'}, 
'3': {'A': '8:32', 'D,': '10:36', 'B': '9:34', 'E': '12:11', 'F': '1:13', 'H,': '2:15'}, 
'2': {'A': '8:32', 'B': '9:34', 'E': '12:11', 'F': '1:13', 'C,': '10:36', 'G,': '2:15'}, 
'5': {'H': '2:15', 'B': '8:40', 'D': '11:00', 'F': '12:55'}, 
'4': {'A': '8:32', 'C': '9:34', 'E': '12:11', 'G': '1:13', 'D,': '10:36', 'H,': '2:15'}, 
'6': {'A': '8:40', 'C': '11:00', 'E': '12:55', 'G': '2:15'}, 
'rotation': 6}
```

As you can see, in day 1, it starts with C instead of B when printing, and the 'rotation' is at the end of the dictionary instead of the front. Why does my dictionary print like this?

Comment: Dictionaries are generally unordered. You can't expect your insertion order to be preserved.

Comment: This question could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784860/why-does-this-python-dictionary-get-created-out-of-order-using-setdefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in a dictionary is not stable, due to the hash function. On top of this, Python now uses a salt value when hashing, meaning that the order will be different each run (except if you ask for a stable dict).

Comment: Okay thank you, how would I tell the dictionary to be stable?

Comment: Check python ordered dict on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary is not required to preserve order. If order is what you want then you could use lists. If you just want to view a dictionary in sorted order, you can use `.sort()` or `sorted()` to help you print.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort this dictionary but you have to make an exception for `rotation` since its values do not fit the rest of the format of being a dictionary with alphabetical keys

```
d = {k: dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])) if k != 'rotation' else schedule[k] for k, v in schedule.items()}
print(d)
# {'rotation': 6, '1': {'B': '8:32', 'C': '9:34', 'D': '10:36', 'F': '12:11', 'G': '1:13', 'H': '2:15'}, '2': {'A': '8:32', 'B': '9:34', 'C,': '10:36', 'E': '12:11', 'F': '1:13', 'G,': '2:15'}, '3': {'A': '8:32', 'B': '9:34', 'D,': '10:36', 'E': '12:11', 'F': '1:13', 'H,': '2:15'}, '4': {'A': '8:32', 'C': '9:34', 'D,': '10:36', 'E': '12:11', 'G': '1:13', 'H,': '2:15'}, '5': {'B': '8:40', 'D': '11:00', 'F': '12:55', 'H': '2:15'}, '6': {'A': '8:40', 'C': '11:00', 'E': '12:55', 'G': '2:15'}}
```